Gradle build failure: Error while executing JdkImageTransform for Android SDK XML version 4 after switching to a new Mac, Could not resolve all files
I’m encountering a Gradle build failure when trying to run my Flutter app on a new Mac. This project was working fine on my previous laptop, but since switching to a Mac, the build process fails. I have tried multiple Java versions and ensured compatibility with Gradle, but nothing has worked.
Here is the full error message:
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':device_info_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':device_info_plus:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/novostack/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/novostack/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/3be12b51fb10ef20077e84b3313a7db4/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/novostack/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/3be12b51fb10ef20077e84b3313a7db4/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 28s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Environment:
Current Setup:
Laptop: MacBook (macOS 15.0 24A335, ARM64)
Flutter: 3.24.5
Dart: 2.19.1
Android Studio: 2024.2.1 Patch 1
Java: java version "21.0.5" 2024-10-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21.0.5+9-LTS-239)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.5+9-LTS-239, mixed mode, sharing)
Gradle: 8.4
What I’ve Tried:
Running flutter clean.
Reinstalling Android SDK tools.
Trying different Java versions (including 17, 21, etc.).
Validating Gradle compatibility with Java.
Ensuring that the necessary licenses for the Android SDK are accepted.
Removing device info plus than it will gives error with different package.
Question:
How can I resolve this build issue and ensure compatibility on my new Mac? Is this related to the SDK XML version 4 warning or a mismatch between Java, Gradle, and the Flutter setup on my machine?
Any guidance or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.
